# How to touch all fields in redux form when we pre-populate values into the form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using a redux wizard form to allow the users to create an application form. 
The users have the ability to save the form filling process mid way and come back and re-edit it.

The problem is , when the users try to re-edit the application form, I populate all the form fields from the values the user had saved. But redux form doesn't enable the next button as the fields are not touched in this case.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try dispatching the `touch` action.

Comment: Redux form should still submit even if the fields are not touched - when you say "next" button is that your submit button?